# R reference filtering column by variable name

Tags: r

Is there a way to get a filtered data frame, like this:

```
data[data$Measure=="Baseline",]
```

using a variable Name for Measure, i.e. measVarName == "Measure"?

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you can't use variables with `$` but you can with `[` and `[[`. So `data[data[[measVarName]] == "Baseline", ]`

Comment: Look at this example: `measVarName <- "mpg"; mtcars[mtcars[measVarName]==19.2,]`

Answer (score 3):

Double bracket notation lets you select variables using a character string stored in a variable:

```
measVarName <- 'Measure'
data[data[[measVarName]] == 'Baseline',]
```